# How do I find if one element contains a value from another element ignoring case in XML using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I want to check if one of my XML elements contains a value another element ignoring case.

Here is what I tried:

```
string title = xhtmldoc.Root.Element(htmlNamespace + "head").Element(htmlNamespace + "title").Value;
TextBoxPublisher.Text = xhtmldoc.Descendants(htmlNamespace + "p").FirstOrDefault(copy => copy.Value.Contains(title, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Value;
```

This is wrong. How shall I proceed?

Comment: Did it work? what issue you are facing?

Comment: `(title, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`, this part is not correct. It is showing an error.

Comment: What error it shows?

Comment: I don't believe you can use `Contains` in this context using the `StringComparison`. If you want to ignore the case, you can convert both the `copy` and `title` variables to lowercase. Try `...FirstOrDefault(copy => copy.Value.ToLower().Contains(title.ToLower())).Value;` in your second line of code.

Comment: Perfect output :)